# Vue component can't find #app when extending layout

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When extending a layout that contains a div with the id of "app" the vue elements will not load, and give the error "Cannot find element: #app"

I tried making a new layout, which is just the @yield wrapped in a div with an id of app, and a very simple component and get the same results.

ExampleComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        {{ count }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    }
    }
</script>
```

app.js

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.new')

@section('content')
    <example-component></example-component>
@endsection
```

new.blade.php

```
<head>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Hello
    <div id="app">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

I expect the number 0 to appear on the page, but nothing is shown and in the console there is an error:

> "[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app"

When inspecting the page the example component is wrapped in a div with an id of app.
[image: HTML Layout]

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `app.js` script will execute first before the `#app` div has been loaded.

Put your script at the end of the `<body>` tag instead of inside the `<head>`:

```
<body>
    Hello
    <div id="app">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. What is confusing me is that I was just working on a project that had an almost identical layout (where the script was in the header) and it was working fine. The only real difference is that it was also using Vuex

Comment: If you put your main script in the head, then you probably need to defer instantiating the main Vue instance until the DOM has loaded (i.e. wait for the `DOMContentLoaded` event).